# How we can get product information by using custom attribute?

Tags: magento2

We can get product information in Magento 1.x by using:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('barcode', '12121');
```

How we can use this method in Magento 2.x?

Answer (score 0):

You can inject `ProductFactory` and use `$this->productFactory->create()` to load product information in Magento 2.

Something like this

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory ProductFactory;

class LoadProduct
{
    protected $productFactory;

    public function __construct(ProductFactory $productFactory)
    {
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
    }

    public function loadProductByBarCode()
    {
        return $this->productFactory->create()->loadByAttribute('barcode', '12121');
    }
}
```

Or, you can also use `ProductRepository` and `ProductCollection`.

Comment: @IqbalMalik so the above solution is working or not?

Comment: in which file this code has to be used? controller? or block?

Comment: This sounds like a great idea, but this depends on your use case. I've experienced that sometimes it decides to not load the product, if it is not in stock.